# postgres container gives no relations inside the container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to launch a PostgreSQL database container. When the container gets launched, I also want the schema and tables to be created in it. By mounting volume and running dql file inside dockerEntrypoint my schema and tables are getting created ( logs say so ).

However , `\dt` gives 'no relations'. Why is this so?

Can you please help

Logs Below:

```
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok


Success. You can now start the database server using:
pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
waiting for server to start....2020-08-05 08:49:25.407 UTC [46] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-05 08:49:25.409 UTC [46] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-05 08:49:25.428 UTC [47] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-05 08:49:25 UTC
2020-08-05 08:49:25.433 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/imcsysdb.sql
CREATE SCHEMA
CREATE TABLE


2020-08-05 08:49:25.654 UTC [46] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2020-08-05 08:49:25.656 UTC [46] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-08-05 08:49:25.657 UTC [46] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 53) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-05 08:49:25.658 UTC [48] LOG:  shutting down
2020-08-05 08:49:25.675 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2020-08-05 08:49:25.768 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-05 08:49:25.769 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-08-05 08:49:25.769 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2020-08-05 08:49:25.772 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-05 08:49:25.789 UTC [73] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-05 08:49:25 UTC
2020-08-05 08:49:25.794 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_DB MYAPP
COPY /myappddl.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Comment: How is your docker run command or docker-compose look like? logs mean no thing without these required information

Comment: sudo docker run -d  --name myapp-postgres-container  -p 5432:5432 -v /opt/pg_import:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ myapp-postgres-image

Comment: I have placed my .sql file inside /opt/pg_import

Comment: is your pg_import create database?

Comment: No. I have placed my .sql file inside directory /opt/pg_import .  So, pg_import is a directory. The .sql file contents below:

Comment: create schema "MYAPP";
CREATE TABLE "MYAPP"."ACCESS_MASTER" ("ACCESS_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,"ROLE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

Comment: have updated dockerfile contents above

Comment: I guess this is resolved as part of the solution provided to you in your other question at [Not able to view any relations inside the created schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63296082/not-able-to-view-any-relations-inside-the-created-schema/63296266?noredirect=1#comment111926382_63296266)

Answer (score 0):

In psql, execute

```
\c "MYAPP"
set search_path to "MYAPP";
\dt
```

Can you see the table now?

I would suggest against creating entities with capital letters in PostgreSQL. It makes maintenance much harder because unlike Oracle Database, the default case is lower-case in PostgreSQL. You will have to use double-quotes whenever accessing any upper-case or mixed-case entity.