# Not able to view any relations inside the created schema

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have launched a postgres container. It creates Schemas and tables through .sql file placed in docker-entrypoint folder. My schema is listed in \dn+. But \dt gives no relations. Access Privileges are intact.

**Doing \dn+ gives:**

```
 List of schemas:

  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 MYAPP    | postgres |                      |
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | =UC/postgres         |
```

**Doing \dt gives:** ( inside public schema )

```
 Did not find any relations.
```

However my .sql file can create tables inside public schema inside same DB. And \dt shows list of tables correctly.

Why I am not able to create tables inside non-public schema . Any privilege constraints?

**sql content below:**

```
CREATE SCHEMA "MYAPP";

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA MYAPP TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE "MYAPP"."ACCESS_MASTER" ("ACCESS_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,"ROLE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

What's wrong here? Please guide.

Edit :

IMCDB=# \dn

```
 List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner
--------+----------
 MYAPP   | postgres
 public | postgres
(2 rows)

MYAPP=# \dt
Did not find any relations.

IMCDB=# set search_path="MYAPP";
SET

MYAPP=# \dt
Did not find any relations.

MYAPP=# show search_path;
 search_path
-------------
 "MYAPP"
(1 row)

MYAPP=# \dt
Did not find any relations.
MYAPP=#
```

Setting the path to my schema didn't help too.

Comment: You need to double-quote your schema name `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "MYAPP" TO postgres;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\dt will only list relations that are present in your default schema which is public in your case.

You need to SET search_path to MYAPP, after that, it will list all relations present in schema MYAPP.

```
postgres=# show search_path;
LOG:  statement: show search_path;
   search_path   
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)


postgres=# set search_path="MYAPP";
SET

postgres=# show search_path;

 search_path 
-------------
 "MYAPP"
(1 row)
```

Comment: @ Amjad. thanks for response. But setting the search path to My scema deidn't help either. Have updated the results above. Please help

Comment: You need to double-quote your schema name `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "MYAPP" TO postgres; ` let me know if that helps?

Comment: Oh !! I missed that.. It is working now. Thanks much Amjad. Accepting the answer. Have a good day.